# What is proper code to add a Default value in Combo Box?

Tags: ms-access, vba

While my current code works to open an report If i enter a value into the Default of the Combo Box it thinks it is a report to open. Current code...

```
Private Sub Command531_Click()
   If Not IsNull(ComboReports) And ComboReports <> "" Then
DoCmd.OpenReport ComboReports, acViewPreview, acWindowNormal
   Else
     MsgBox ("You Must First Select a Report To Open!")
     ComboReports.SetFocus
   End If
   ComboReports = ""
End Sub
```

I would like to have "Select Report" as the default value in the Combo box. What am I doing Wrong??

Thanks in Advance,
Jerry

Comment: ComboBox Properties => Open in Design View =>  Data tab => Look for Default Value property and enter your value

Comment: Thats where I am entering it. The combo box is linked to the following query SELECT MsysObjects.Name FROM MsysObjects WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=-32764)) ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;           when I enter a default value the button mentioned above thinks that "Select Report" is an actual report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you

```
Private Sub Command531_Click()
     If Nz(ComboReports, "") <> "" And Nz(ComboReports, "") <> "Select Report" Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport ComboReports, acViewPreview, acWindowNormal
   Else
     MsgBox ("You Must First Select a Report To Open!")
     ComboReports.SetFocus
   End If
   ComboReports = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are trying to assign a default value to your comb box that does not belong to the its value set.

If your `RowSource` is

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name FROM MsysObjects WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=-32764)) ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name
```

try using this for `RowSource`

```
SELECT Name FROM MsysObjects WHERE Left(Name,1)<>'~' AND Type=-32764
UNION
SELECT ' Select Report' AS Name
ORDER BY Name
```

The space in ' Select Report' is intentional to push it to the top of the order.